# upgrading to pcl 1.3 in electric

Tags: pcl, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use some features that are specific to pcl 1.3; I believe 1.0 or 1.1 is in the electric release?

So I downloaded/installed the (non-ROS) pcl 1.3 package with apt. But now the build system gets confused, and will compile against the 1.3 headers but link against the 1.0 libraries.

Errors appear as follows (*many* of these):

```
CMakeFiles/pcl_test.dir/src/pcl_test.o:
(.rodata._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_11PointXYZRGBEEE[vtable for pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZRGB>]+0x68):
undefined reference to `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::radiusSearch(int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, int) const'
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
#...
rosbuild_init()
#...
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

rosbuild_add_executable(pcl_test src/pcl_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcl_test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

manifest.xml declares dependencies on pcl and pcl_ros (I have also tried omitting these deps, in the hopes the linker would then do The Right Thing)

Thanks mucho!

-Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11868/upgrading-to-pcl-1.3-in-electric/) by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the answers to this [similar question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2608/how-do-you-upgrade-pcl-to-the-current-release).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0